# SP2-0552: Bind variable "NEW" not declared and END Error report - Unknown Command

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to write a trigger for the tables I made and in insert update, I have to record a separate log table for those that are updated or inserted.

Columns in the log table will be like;

- Done_process (will write update, insert)
- Person (student number of the person treated)
- Before (previous value for update, blank for insert)
- After (new value for update, new value for insert)

This is my `student_info` table,

```
CREATE TABLE student_info (
    school_id NUMBER,
    id_no NUMBER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    surname VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student_info_pk PRIMARY KEY(school_id )
);

CREATE TABLE og_log(
        done_process VARCHAR2(30),
        person VARCHAR2(30),
        before VARCHAR2(30),
        after VARCHAR2(30)
    );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER og_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON student_info
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING THEN 
      INSERT INTO og_log(done_process, person, before, after)
       VALUES ('Insert',:new.school_id,:old.name,:new.name);
   ELSIF UPDATING THEN
     INSERT INTO og_log(done_process, person, before, after)
       VALUES ('Update',:new.school_id,:old.name,:new.name);
   END IF;
END;
/
```

When I try to run the code it gave an error as follows;

```
> Trıgger OG_TRIGGER created.
> 
> 
> Error starting at line : 280 in command - ELSIF UPDATING THEN Error
> report - Unknown Command
> 
> SP2-0552: Bind variable "NEW" not declared.
> 
> 0 rows inserted.
> 
> 
> Error starting at line : 283 in command - END IF Error report -
> Unknown Command
> 
> SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP and to leave enter
> EXIT.
> 
> Error starting at line : 284 in command - END Error report - Unknown
> Command
```

Comment: show us the description of your `student_info` table

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I edited my question now you can see my `student_info` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are creating this trigger for learning purpose and not something a real use case because what you do in trigger doesn't really making any sense.

The trigger you have mentioned is not compiling due to syntactical problems like `where v_id := 20201033`.

Where clause is used to compare the value and thus you should use `=` instead `:=` which is an assignment operator.

Besides this problem few points which still needs to be taken care

1. Give a explicit convention for creating local variables. e.g. you have created a local variable `v_id` and the same column is also available in `student_info` table. Though it is not a problem in this case but it's good practice to keep the local variable specific like let's say `l_v_id`.
2. You have used a select statement inside trigger which could leads to `NO_DATA_FOUND` error and you should handle it by either in the exception section or another way would be using aggregate function like `max()` if obviously `v_id` is primary key. *I doubt why you need this select statement ( you could use between old and new using something like  `coalesce(:old.school_id,:new_schoold_id)` if I understood you)   but I would leave it open to you to decide and act accordingly*.

Considering above points final code will be,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER og_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON student_info
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING THEN 
      INSERT INTO og_log(done_process, person, before, after)
       VALUES ('Insert',:new.school_id,:old.city,:new.city);
   ELSIF UPDATING THEN
     INSERT INTO og_log(done_process, person, before, after)
       VALUES ('Update',:new.school_id,:old.city,:new.city);
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Find demo [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e82c29c3621ef4586ce5a5a97e1e435)

---

---

**EDITED: Solving probably tool issue**

I doubt the issue is with SQL Developer tool usage , however last try i would like to make,

**Step1:**
Drop both the tables used by issuing drop command

```
drop table STUDENT_INFO;
drop table og_log;
```

**Step2:**
Open another SQL worksheet using `alt+F10` and do as I have shown in the following image. Please try and let me know.

[image]

Comment: I want to print the student's id in the person column but in your demo, I didn't see that. Also, v_id is not in the student_info table. Simply, what I want to do is made insertion in 1 student and I want to show this student's id. I hope I explained my question well to you.

Comment: No you didn't. I don't know why you want. What do you mean by print ? If you just need print you might not need trigger. In your original question, you do select `school_id` not `student_id` in the select clause and insert into `person` column of `og_log` table. If `v_id` is not in the table why do you add in the `where clause`  ?

Comment: ***`Simply, what I want to do is made insertion in 1 student and I want to show this student's id. I hope I explained my question well to you***` : I have no idea what you mean by this ? If you simply want to insert and show then why you need trigger ? I wanted to help by what I see in your code and what is in your mind and this is the reason you have to ask the question properly.

Comment: I want to write a trigger that can insert or update the column I made it and  I want to store in the og_log. And I also try to write a specific school id to show which student I am doing, I want her/his school number to appear in the person column.

Comment: @Ezgi, sorry to say i am confused with what you want. I just edited the code. Could you check and let me know ?

Comment: I looked at your code and trying now but insert if I want to insert new info what I can do? Must I add a new column in student_info table?

Comment: what kind of  `new info` you want to insert ?

Comment: like mother name or something else about student

Comment: Yes anything new `attribute` you want to store for a student, you want to add a column to the `student_info` table. Also keep in mind when you are in trigger you have always access to all the column in the `student_info` table which you can access via `:old.<column_name>` and `:new.<column_name>` but `:new.<column_name >` will not be there in case of delete.

Comment: I try your code and it gives error something like this: `Trıgger OG_TRIGGER created.

Error starting at line : 280 in command -
   ELSIF UPDATING THEN
Error report -
Unknown Command

SP2-0552: Bind variable "NEW" not declared.

0 rows inserted.`


`Error starting at line : 283 in command -
   END IF
Error report -
Unknown Command

SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.

Error starting at line : 284 in command -
END
Error report -
Unknown Command`

Comment: I am sorry I am out of this and you are on your own. I have not done something for me only and it as per oracle database. I don't know what you are doing and where you are doing. Please check this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a323b1246857093f13f78d4c9d739122  It all worked and then only I post.

Comment: Which tool are using ? i mean where do you compile you code ?

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Check the trigger in the object browser (left hand panel, below Connections), and see if it's marked with a red or not ? then you can right-click the trigger name in the browser tree and select 'Edit' which will open the code editor window and it shouldn't get confused about bind variables hopefully

Comment: Alternatively when you say in previous comments `Trıgger OG_TRIGGER created.  Error starting at line : 280 in command -    ELSIF UPDATING THEN Error report`........ type `show errors` and check.....